# Redirect URLs without .htaccess

Tags: php, url, webserver

I have a website that contains URLs in this format `www.example.com/jobs.php?id=123456`

All URLs are stored in a database.

I want to make SEO friendly URLs (example:`www.example.com/this-is-my-first-job`)

I have built this website in php.

is it possible to generate SEO friendly urls from the current format without modifying the `.htaccess` file ?

Comment: What do you mean by "core php"? Are you talking about PHP's built in web server?

Comment: put this Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/this-is-my-first-job/$1 [R=301,L] in your .httpd the conf file followed by RewriteEngine on -- make sure mod rewrite is turned on.

Comment: or you can use php redirect header('Location: http://www.gotourl.com');

Comment: Clarified a bit on what the OP was trying to say, added terms like `SEO friendly` to make it clear what's being asked

Comment: @gojobs, i don't think your problem is PHP related, you need to configure your webserver to do that, what webserver are you using ? you are looking at something that `mod_rewrite` should be doing for you

Comment: @MagnusEriksson core php means "no any framework of php like laravel etc"

Comment: @unixmiah No you did not understand my question. Please see my answer below. I have elaborated.

Comment: @MostafaTorbjørnBerg Yes I want to make URLs SEO friendly.

Comment: @gojobs then you need to do that without PHP, you need to look into mod_rewrite as other users are recommending

Comment: @gojobs if you're using a cms, you should be able to do that from your edit content panel to generate SEO friendly urls. otherwise, you'll have to modify your .htaccess file.

Answer (score 0):

I am saying simple.

When someone post a job to my website, I store all information in database and generate a unique key (let say 123456) and populate on a single page based on the URL that would be `www.somewebsite.com?mypage?id=123456`
Now I want the existing url to be changed.
I want that when user hit this URL, he will automatically be redirected to some different URL that is stored in database too.

Comment: What is the reason for not using .htaccess? If you will host the site on a Apache-web server, then that's what I would use, or set up the rewrite in the vhost. Redirect all calls to /index.php and have a router that handles the routing. If you're using some other web server, check the docs on how to use "url rewrite" on that server to do the same. PHP can't do the rewrite on it's own. (unless you're using PHP's internal web server, then it's slightly different). It's the web server that takes the request and decides what to do.

Comment: I have no problem using .htaccess. If I get some good solution with that, I am ok.
The main problem is my URLs create automatically and it grows. then how can I use .htacess?

Comment: I want that there must be some check that will redirect my URL to some different URL stored in same row in database. something like this is appreciable.

Comment: Like I said, you redirect all calls to one page, like /index.php and set up a router, using something like [Phroute](https://github.com/mrjgreen/phroute). There you can set up dynamic routes (using parameters etc.).

Comment: you need .htaccess for that- it's a url you're generating, you need to translate your dynamic url in order to have a friendly url. it's better that you're urls are generating dynamically, because in mod rewrite you can create conditions which will support it.

Answer (score 0):

As far i understand your question, first you need .htaccess for SEO friendly URL. Now, for example `www.example.com/jobs.php?id=123456` is an URL and you want to redirect the user to `www.example.com/this-is-my-first-job` which is stored in database.
Let see,

```
if(isset($_GET['id'])){
   //get the slug from database against id
   header("Location: www.example.com/".$slug);
 }
```

How to get the id from slug?

write in .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*)$ index.php?slug=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

now in PHP

```
    if(isset($_GET['slug'])){
     //get the id from database against slug
     }
```

Comment: Question is without .htaccess.